Water flowing between two tanks in a closed system where the flow is driven by salinity differences
I have a question about the classic two tank problem in differential equations.
These problems always give you a rate of flow between the two tanks. However, if I had a closed system, and the tanks were connected by two pipes where only natural flow could occur, how could I model this? Imagine one tank is highly saline and the other freshwater. Is there a relationship I could set for the rate of flow of the water from the freshwater to saline water?
EDIT: Here is an image.
EDIT: This question was closed for lack of clarity. I genuinely just do not have as much knowledge of physics, and I am trying to develop an understanding of where to start. :( Is this not okay on this site? If so, that's rather disappointing and maybe I should continue developing an understanding elsewhere... :\


Why would bulk flow occur in a closed system of two tanks connected by pipes? Alternatively, are you asking about diffusion times? Please clarify—what are you ultimately trying to do?

I guess I am interested in the rate of flow to reach equilibrium since the freshwater will travel to the salt water in one tube and push some salt water into the freshwater into the other tube. I know there is likely added issues of friction, type of flow, etc., but mostly looking for a simpler way to understand this mathematically. Also, I added a diagram in my original post. It's likely that I'm talking about diffusion times, but my knowledge of physics isn't great (my degree is in math).

You can check out Stommel’s model, where the flow is also driven by a temperature gradient.

That's what I am actually trying to understand, but there are oversimplifications that makes it hard to explain why every decision within the equation was made.

For example, for the container that warms, a differential equation describing that is dT_equatorial/dt = c(T_equilibrium - T_equatorial) - q(T_equatorial - T_polar), where q = k(alpha*(T_equatorial-T_polar) - beta*(S_equatorial - S_polar). However, why is q multiplied by (T_equatorial-T_polar)? Why would this work? Maybe a fraction of warm leaves and cold enters. Still not intuitive and, if I explained this to someone else, they would not be satisfied.

Did you check out Stommel's original article "Thermohaline Convection with Two Stable Regimes of Flow"? It's very didactic and illustrates it clearly with an experimental setup. $c$ captures the linear relaxation due to diffusion, while $q$ is the flow which physically represents the thermohaline circulation. The flow is buoyancy driven, which is why it is proportional to the difference in salinity and temperature (linear expansion approximation).

Btw, if you edit your question and mention the context and physical setup (reference to the article, equations of the model...), it could be reopened.

I am voting to reopen this question. The OP is basically stating that from experience he knows water tends to migrate from a saline tank to a freshwater tank but does not understand the physical process that bring that about. In other words he is trying to understand the conceptual physics behind the phenomena.  Isn't that one of purposes of this forum? The question he is asking appears perfectly clear to me.

Yeah, I have read Stommel's original paper. I think I have a hard time with this linear approximation because density/flow behaves in much more complicated ways, which makes me feel I don't understand the essence of his paper. My understanding is that temperature and salinity have opposing effects on the flow, and both salinity and temperature affect density in opposite ways. However, it's not true that density differences are directly proportional to the rate of flow which has confused be regarding why it would be ok to have a linear approximation... also isn't the equation of state complex?

To make things simpler place the connecting pipes right near the top and bottom so that the difference in their heights is the basically the same as the heights of the tanks.
Since seawater is denser that fresh water, the situation is equivalent to having two freshwater tanks with a higher level in one of them. This effective freshwater pressure head difference will drive the seawater from its tank to the freshwater tank and induce a matching flow in the opposite direction in the top pipe, due to displacement. The flow due to head pressure will be more significant than diffusion flow.
The water head in the freshwater tank is simply the height of the tanks (h). The equivalent water pressure head in the seawater tank is  $$ h \frac{\rho_S}{\rho_W}, $$  where $\rho_S$ is the density of the seawater and $\rho_W$ is the density of water. The difference in water heads of the two tanks is  $$ h \left( \frac{\rho_S}{\rho_W} -1 \right) .$$
You now have $\Delta h$ expressed in terms of water head, as if they were both filled with water, but at different heights, that can be entered into the standard equation for water flow, as described in this water flow calculator.
However as the seawater flows into the freshwater tank there will be mixing and the density in the freshwater tank will rise, and the displaced freshwater returning to the seawater tank via the the top pipe will dilute the contents of that tank and eventually the densities will equalise and the flow will stop.
You will have do some calculus to allow for the continually changing densities, but I will leave that to you as the math expert ;-)
The bulk flow due to diffusive mass transport arising from differences in concentrations in the two tanks can probably be ignored as the mass transport effect in the top pipe tends to work in the opposite direction to the mass transport effect in the bottom pipe, but there will be a small contribution to the equalising of concentrations due to this effect .
If the lower pipe is significantly higher than the bottom of the tanks, or the upper pipe is significantly lower than the top of the tanks, then there will be dead spaces, where mixing is not significant and then you will have to take diffusion into account.
In the context of circulation in oceans, salinity changes and temperature changes affect the density of the seawater that in turn drives the circulation. Cooling in the Northern regions causes the seawater to sink there and flow at lower depths towards the equator where it warms up, rises and flows back towards the North in the surface layers, due to displacement. See thermohaline ocean circulation.

Why does multiplying h by ρs/ρw tell us the equivalent water pressure
head in the seawater tank? -AAAA

The pressure at the bottom of a vessel is the force (F) due to the weight (m g) of the liquid acting on the horizontal cross sectional area (A) so
$$ P = \frac FA = \frac {m g}{A} = \frac {\rho \ V \ g}{A} = \rho\  g \ h$$
where V is the volume of water above. It can be seen if the height is tripled the pressure is tripled and the same result can be achieved by tripling the density. i.e. $ \rho\  g \ (3 h) = (3\rho)\  g \ h$. Therefore the pressure head of a given height of a liquid with greater density than that of water is equivalent to a greater height of water. If the tanks were connected by only a single pipe at the bottom and the left side was filled with mercury and the right side with water (to the same height), the greater weight of the contents of the left tank will cause the mercury to flow into the water tank and raise the level in the right tank and drop the level in the right tank. At equilibrium the level in the right side will be much higher than the level in the left side so we can say the a given height of mercury is equivalent to greater height of water.  (The connecting pipe could be very long and prefilled with water so that mercury does not actually enter the water tank.)

+1. Note that osmosis and osmotic pressure refers to a semipermeable membrane, which doesn’t seem to be present. The mixing mechanisms here are pressure-driven flow and diffusive mass transport, as you describe.

@Chemomechanics Thanks. You are right. I was wrong to call it osmotic pressure. I have edited my post accordingly.

Thanks! Sometimes the connections made in physics confuse me a bit. Why does multiplying h by ρs/ρw tell us the equivalent water pressure head in the seawater tank? I don't think I have a full conceptual understanding of what this means and why they are multiplied.
